# Running a Script

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

I have a Python script running that checks to see if slots have opened up for a 
class I want to take next semester, and then it emails me.
**Problem**
I can't have my laptop in all the time. Is there any resource available to let me house my script and just let it run on some server.

Or better yet, is there anyway to run a script like this on an Android phone.

Comment: I believe heroku now supports Python 3. It would take a bit of fiddling to slot the code into a web framework, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are scraping a web page, you could use [scraperwiki](https://scraperwiki.com/). It allows you to run scraper code on their server for free. ([lxml](http://lxml.de/) is importable there too!) You can set how frequently you want the script to run.

Comment: Scripts in python 3 that only supports 2.7

Comment: Okay, I will delete this post. If you are looking for an Android solution, you may get more responses by adding the `android` tag to your question.

Comment: No need to delete it im glad you posted it. Scraper wiki sounds like a great resources.